# How to simplify this complex syntax and ambiguous word usage?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity, syntactic-analysis, paraphrasing

I couldn't understand a sentence in a literary work which is too complex and containing too much terminology. Can you help me understand the sentence by just **simplifying** or re-organazing or re-arranging or paraphrasing the sentence? I couldn't get where are the verb, the object, the subject and evereything. I'm also having problems with the usage of the words like what words used to mean what.(For example 'reflection' or 'object'. Reflection for 'echo' or 'thinking'? Object for 'protest' or 'aim' or 'thing?') My head's become a mess. The sentence I need to understand is written in **bold** and I am also quoting the context:

> But, for these reasons, shall we be justified in imagining the atoms heterogeneous, dissimilar, unequal, and inequidistant? More explicitly—are we to consider no two atoms as, at their diffusion, of the same nature, or of the same form, or of the same size?—and, after fulfilment of their diffusion into Space, is absolute inequidistance, each from each, to be understood of all of them? In such arrangement, under such conditions, we most easily and immediately comprehend the subsequent most feasible carrying out to completion of any such design as that which I have suggested—the design of variety out of unity—diversity out of sameness—heterogeneity out of homogeneity—complexity out of simplicity—in a word, the utmost possible multiplicity of relation out of the emphatically irrelative One. **Undoubtedly, therefore, we should be warranted in assuming all that has been mentioned, but for the reflection, first, that supererogation is not presumable of any Divine Act; and, secondly, that the object supposed in view, appears as feasible when some of the conditions in question are dispensed with, in the beginning, as when all are understood immediately to exist.** I mean to say that some are involved in the rest, or so instantaneous a consequence of them as to make the distinction inappreciable. Difference of size, for example, will at once be brought about through the tendency of one atom to a second, in preference to a third, on account of particular inequidistance; which is to be comprehended as particular inequidistances between centres of quantity, in neighboring atoms of different form—a matter not at all interfering with the generally-equable distribution of the atoms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this makes sense.

> Certainly, therefore, we would be justified in assuming the above
> (what has just been said), if it weren't for (except for) these two
> thoughts: A) we can't suppose (assume) that any Divine Act entails
> more work than duty requires; and B) the result (ie utmost
> multiplicity) looks as feasible when some of the conditions(1) are
> absent at the beginning as it does when they are present.
>
> (1) ie those conditions described in lines 1 to 3.

I'm not certain I understand it completely. It's extremely difficult, Batuhan!

Comment: Oh! Now, it really sounds something. Thank you very much. I got the idea. Trying to comprehend the text verbatim shall be supererogatory, I think.

Comment: :-) Yes! *Very* supererogatory!

Answer (score 1):

It is admittedly an example of tortured writing.

But here's an attempt at simplification. However, I can't really help the author improve their conceptualizations!

> It's OK (warranted) to assume that the ideas that were mentioned above are
> true, except for two thoughts (reflections) we want to add:
>
> 1. We can't assume that God has done more than the minimum required (acts of God cannot be presumed supererogatory)
> 2. Not all of these conditions are necessary to believe the conclusion.  OR  The conclusion/result (object) seems as likely (to exist?) when we throw away some of the proposed conditions, just as they would exist if all of the proposed conditions existed from the beginning.

It's unclear exactly what the sentence is saying without more context. But in short, it seems the author is responding to someone else's argument by saying:

I'm comfortable with the assumptions made, except that we didn't need all of the preconditions to come to those conclusions, and we need not think God has done anything extra here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to digest your writings for some time. It is very useful. However; there are still blurred points in my mind since English is not my mother tongue, maybe. I am still trying to fit everything together. Actually, I got the idea of he first part but the second is still weak. Where did the 'object' come from into the context? I thought he was just writing about atoms etc. not concrete and formed 'objects.' I thought it was rather an 'objection to a suggestion' but again I couldn't fit it in the context. Guess my English is not enough for this text.

Comment: I think the 'object' means the 'target' or 'result' here.

Comment: Oh, yes , ‘the result.’ Now it makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good point, that helps. "Object" was one word that just didn't make sense without further context from earlier in the passage. I'll make a minor edit to clarify that.